# HP 2605n "paper jam" - doesn't feed paper

Tags: printer, laser-printer, paper-tray

I have an HP 2605n printer and every time I try to print the paper doesn't feed and the printer says it has a "paper jam". I've taken out the pick-up roller and cleaned it off, but it appears to be new and not smooth at all (very rubbery/bumpy).

I've noticed that I can sometimes force the printer to print by wiggling a small knob on the front of the paper tray up and down.[image] The printer also makes a squeaking sound unless I force it to print this way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The knob is a paper gauge that shows content of the tray.  Check the tray carefully for a small scrap of paper and the pickup area at the back of the tray.  You may need a strong light.  One small piece near a sensor will give grief.  Check all paper rollers.

Is the toner an HP toner or a remanufactured one?

Comment: It is HP  toner. Where is the sensor located?

Comment: I do not know without a manual for the printer.  Each is different.  Looking for a small piece of paper or a sign of damage would be my first step without a manual.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. I am able to take the tray out and hold down the lever that detects the tray and it looks as if everything is working properly but then it still says paper jam.

Comment: I was reading the manual and it says you can insert paper through the front of the tray. http://gyazo.com/65daec34b0303e2191608f36845fae65.png Doing this works, but printing from the tray itself does not.

Comment: That would point me to a problem with the tray or a sensor in the feed area for the tray.  Check the mechanisim on the small knob you describe.  That is somehow connected to a sensor that indicates if there is paper in the tray.  A service manual will be needed to dive deeper into this.